# Hide or customize TextFilter in ListView

Tags: android, listview

How hide TextFilter window (with entered letters)?
I talk about letters appearing when typing on listview if `setTextFilterEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a TextFilter widget? You can hide a TextView (with or without an applied filter) with [setVisibility(](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)).

Comment: Its not textview. I talk about letters appears when typing on listview if "setTextFilterEnabled(true)"